# Using android listview with keylistener

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onkeydown

Hello i'm developping an app for Android device.
And i'm trying to implement a Keylistener on a Listview.
But if my listview has a lot of elements, my Keylistener is not called by the apps instead it's use the default keylistner for the Listview.
Do you have any clue about this situation?
I'm proceed this way to bind the keylistner to my listview.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tv_fragment_channel_list, container);
adapter = new AdapterChannelList(getActivity(), ( (List<Category>) User.getInstance().getTV() ).get(0).getContent());
list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.channelListview);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
        switch (keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadVideo(mLiveTv.get(
                                         ListId).getUrl(),"TV");
                getZappingBannerFragment().loadChannelInfo(mLiveTv.get(
                                           ListId).getId(), true);
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tvpannel).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                MainActivity.shouldfocus = R.id.videoView1;
                return true;
            }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            {
                if (ListId >= /*6*/mLiveTv.size() -1)
                return true;
                if (ListPos == 10)
                {
                    reduce(ListPos);
                }
                else if (ListId > 10)
                reduce(ListPos);
                else
                reduce(ListId);

                ListId++;
                ListPos++;
                if (ListPos == 10)
                {
                    reduce(ListPos - 1);
                    enlarge(ListPos);
                    list.setSelectionFromTop(ListId, 0);
                    ListPos = 0;
                }
                else if (ListId > 10)
                enlarge(ListPos);
                else
                enlarge(ListId);
                //list.setSelectionFromTop(ListId, 0);
                //list.scrollBy(0, 250);
                return true;
            }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            {
                // list.scrollBy(0, -250);
                if (ListId > 0)
                {
                    reduce(ListId);
                    ListId--;
                    ListPos--;
                }
                if (ListPos < 0)
                {
                    enlarge(ListId);
                    list.setSelectionFromTop(ListPos, 0);
                    ListPos = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    enlarge(ListId);
                }
                //list.setSelectionFromTop(ListId, 0);
                //list.setSelection(ListId);

                return true;
            }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            {
                //getZappingBannerFragment().justShow();
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tvpannel).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.menu_principal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.shouldfocus = R.id.menu_principal;
                return true;
            }
            }
        }
    return true;
    }
});
return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your keyListener respectively to your list row items  from your list adapter. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it's help a lot,
But i'm not understanding why it's working when i have few elements and why it's not working when i have more elements.

Comment: I am not sure about it but I think when you scroll your list view, your view with keyListener recycled. This may make useless your keyListener.

Comment: But doing this way is very Ressource consumming?

Comment: Not actually. You have already used system resources in your list adapter while creating your list row items. Listeners only give you the chance of listening events of related list row item.